# how to convert html reponse of api to simple text but their tag quality

Tags: flutter, dart

get request response in html, the property which i access bassically text appearing with HTML

[here is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq2NG.jpg)
we get array then we parse in json here my fetchAllQuotes method

```
fetchAllQuotes() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://quotes.limpidsol.com/api/quotes'));
    // final quotesData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    final quotesData = quoteModelFromJson(response.body);
    data = quotesData.dataArr.data;

    // print(data);
  }
```

here i get the single quote

```
Iterable<Widget>? plainText() {
    // final quotePlanText1 = data?.map((v) => convertQuoteToPlainStr(v.qoute));
    final quotePlanText = data?.map(
      (v) => Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            '${v.qoute}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return quotePlanText;
  }
```

displaying the build method:
[little and complete code of build method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98fE2.png)
i expecting like this output:
[i expecting the output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5QLj.jpg)

Comment: How about using `Html` widget instead of `Text`?

Answer (score 0):

Either use the [Flutter_HTML package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) to display the data with the html-tags as is, this way you can display the quotes the exact way you get them from the api / they are "intended".
OR use the parser from the [HTML package](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.3.0/dart-html/dart-html-library.html) and strip the data from its html-elements, so you have the quotes in pure text and can edit and display them as you wish.